# On characters of the symmetric group: Part 1

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, partitions

Given an integer partition $\lambda$, denote $\ell(\lambda)=$ length, $\vert\lambda\vert=$ size and $\lambda=$ conjugate of $\lambda$. Allow to write $\lambda\vdash n$ either as $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{\ell})$ or else as $1^{m_1}2^{m_2}\cdots n^{m_n}$.

$\DeclareMathOperator\Ev{Ev}$Define $\Ev(\lambda)={}$the set of all partitions obtained by replacing each $\lambda_i$ with either $2\lambda_i$ (doubling) or $\lambda_i,\lambda_i$ (two copies) and
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{R}_N(2\vert\lambda\vert)&:=\{\mu \vdash 2\vert\lambda\vert: \,\, \ell(\mu)\leq N; \, \text{$\mu_i$ is even for all $i$}\}, \\
\mathcal{R}^c_N(2\vert\lambda\vert)&:=\{\mu \vdash 2\vert\lambda\vert: \,\, \ell(\mu)\leq N; \, \text{$\mu_i'$ is even for all $i$}\}, \\
\chi_{\lambda}^{\mu}&:= \text{the character of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_{\vert\lambda\vert}$ for $\vert\mu\vert=\vert\lambda\vert$}, \\
z_{\lambda}&:=\prod_{j\geq1}m_j!\,j^{m_j}.
\end{align*}
${\color{blue}{\textit{Caveat}}}$: the multiset $\Ev(\lambda)$ has $2^{\ell(\lambda)}$ elements and multiple Young diagrams are allowed.

> **(${\color{red}{\textit{Updated}}}$) MILDER QUESTION.** Is this true? For any $N\geq1$, we have that
> $$\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} \frac1{z_{\lambda}} \,
> \sum_{\tilde{\lambda}\in \Ev(\lambda)} (-1)^{\ell(\tilde{\lambda})}
> \sum_{\mu\, \in \,\mathcal{R}_{2N+1}(2\vert\lambda\vert)} \chi_{\tilde{\lambda}}^{\mu}
> =\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}  \frac1{z_{\lambda}} \,
> \sum_{\tilde{\lambda}\in \Ev(\lambda)}\,\,  \sum_{\mu\, \in\,  \mathcal{R}_{2N}^c(2\vert\lambda\vert)} 
> \chi_{\tilde{\lambda}}^{\mu}.
> $$

**Example.** If $\lambda=111$ then $\Ev(111)=\{222,2211,2211,2211,21111,21111,21111,111111\}$. If, in addition, $N=1$ then $\mathcal{R}_2^c(2\vert111\vert)=\{33\}$ while $\mathcal{R}_3(2\vert111\vert)=\{6, 42, 222\}$.

**Remark.** The limiting case $N\rightarrow\infty$ is true. Indeed, this follows since the elements of
$\mathcal{R}_{\infty}(a)$ and $\mathcal{R}_{\infty}^c(a)$ are transposes of each other.
In such event, it is clear that
$$\chi_{\tilde{\lambda}}^{{\color{red}\mu'}}
=(-1)^{\vert\tilde{\lambda}\vert+\ell(\tilde{\lambda})}\cdot 
\chi_{\tilde{\lambda}}^{{\color{red}\mu}}.$$