# On characters of the symmetric group: Part 2

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, partitions

This question is related to my [earlier MO quest](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460090/on-characters-of-the-symmetric-group-part-1).

For an integer partition $\lambda$, denote $\ell(\lambda)=$ length, $\vert\lambda\vert=$ size and $\lambda=$ conjugate of $\lambda$. Allow to write $\lambda\vdash n$ either as $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_{\ell})$ or else as $1^{m_1}2^{m_2}\cdots n^{m_n}$ for a partition of $n$.

Define $\mathcal{P}_n$ to be the set of all partitions of $n$ and let $2\mathcal{P}_n:=\{2\lambda: \, \lambda\in\mathcal{P}_n\}$. For example,
since $\mathcal{P}_3=\{3, 21, 111\}$ it follows that $2\mathcal{P}_3=\{6, 42, 222\}$. We designate

\begin{align*}
\chi_{\lambda}^{\mu}&:= \text{the character of the symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_{\vert\lambda\vert}$ for $\vert\mu\vert=\vert\lambda\vert$}.
\end{align*}

> **QUESTION.** Is this true? For each $\lambda=1^{m_1}2^{m_2}\cdots \in\mathcal{P}_{2n}$, we have that
> $$\sum_{\mu\in 2\mathcal{P}_n} \,\chi_{\lambda}^{\mu}
> =\prod_{i\geq1}\, \beta_{i,m_i};
> $$
> where
> $$\beta_{i,j}:=\begin{cases} \qquad \qquad 0  
> &\text{if $i$ and $j$ are odd}, \\
> \qquad \frac{i^{j/2}j!}{2^{j/2}(j/2)!}
> &\text{if $i$ is odd and $j$ is even}, \\ 
> \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor j/2\rfloor}\binom{j}k\binom{j-k}kk!\left(\frac{i}2\right)^k 
> &\text{if $i$ is even and $j$ is any}.
> \end{cases} 
> $$